# Is there a way to do delegateToSchema but expose child fields on root level only?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

The parent service gives me a response like this:

```
Notification {
  id
  TWid
}
```

Now I send TWid to child service to get other fields like title, body, etc.
I’m able to resolve a field to child service so that I’m able to query something like this:

```
Notification {
  id
  data {
    title
    body
  }
}
```

But, I want to be able to query like:

```
Notification {
  id
  title
  body
}
```

Is it possible to do this without explicitly resolving for each field? Basically I want to automatically resolve all fields which are not there in the parent schema to child schema.

Answer (score 1):

Doing something like this would be inherently against the schema-based design architecture that makes GraphQL consistent, so my recommendation is to re-visit your schema design as that seems like where the scope of this issue is arising.

You could use a [custom directive](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/gateway/#custom-directive-support) to accomplish this, it'd lead to inconsistent results with your schema though and would be an anti-pattern for GQL schema design.